# How to create separate source sets for different flavors correctly android?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have three flavors:

```
flavorDimensions += listOf("flavour_1", "flavour_2")

    productFlavors {
        create("Flavour1") {
            applicationId = "com.pkg.flavour_1"
            dimension = "flavour_1"
        }

        create("Flavour2") {
            applicationId = "com.pkg.flavour_2"
            dimension = "flavour_1"
        }


        create("Flavour3") {
            applicationId = "com.pkg.flavour_3"
            dimension = "flavour_2"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        getByName("Flavour1") {
            res.srcDirs("src/Flavour1/res")
            java.srcDirs("src/Flavour1/java")
        }

        getByName("Flavour2") {
            res.srcDirs("src/Flavour2/res")
            java.srcDirs("src/Flavour2/java")
        }
    }
```

and I don't understand why I can not find options for adding source folders for Flavour2, only for Flavour1 and Flavour3. I think it is because of different and commong dimension. If yes, so I don't understand for which purpose we need to use common dimension. Also another question is how is it correct to create several MainActivity files for different flavors. I saw several sources which say that when we have flavors we have to remove all .kt classes from `main` root. But in such case the main manifest will be broken. At this moment I managed only to create separate build variants for that flavors.

Comment: "I can not find options for adding source folders", you mean Android studio doesn't offer you an option or when you create it manually it doesn't register files? The Activity thing - have Manifest for the given flavors - they merge into one at the end.

Comment: yes, I mean that when you press right button on the source folder you do not have any suggestions like "desired_flavor/java" or smth like that.

Comment: What is it that you actually want? Do you want 3 flavors of the same app or do you want a combination of (`Flavour1` | `Flavour2`) with `Flavour3`?

Comment: Three flavors, separately without combination

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you want three flavors, it makes it a bit easier - you need only 1 dimension.

`flavorDimensions` are not `productFlavors`.

Think of `dimensions` as [Spinners](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/spinner) where created `flavors` are the items in the spinner.

```
flavorDimensions += listOf("brand")

productFlavors {
    create("Brand1") {
        ...
        dimension = "brand"
    }

    create("Brand2") {
        ...
        dimension = "brand"
    }

    create("Brand3") {
        ...
        dimension = "brand"
    }
}
```

That was basically it, just remove the second dimension.

```
sourceSets {
    getByName("Brand1") {
        res.srcDirs("src/Brand1/res")
        java.srcDirs("src/Brand1/java")
    }

    getByName("Brand2") {
        res.srcDirs("src/Brand2/res")
        java.srcDirs("src/Brand2/java")
    }

    getByName("Brand3") {
        res.srcDirs("src/Brand3/res")
        java.srcDirs("src/Brand3/java")
        manifest.srcFile("src/Brand3/AndroidManifest.xml")
    }
}
```

The following bit assumes your original code - `flavorDimensions += listOf("flavour_1", "flavour_2")`

What was happening was that Gradle was trying to create all possible variations of product dimensions - **the order matters**.
With your dimensions, Gradle will try to create variants in this manner.

```
flavor_1 * flavor_2 * buildTypes(debug/release)
```

Resulting in:

```
Flavour1 * Flavour3 * Debug
Flavour2            * Release
```

Now regarding sources. You don't have to remove everything from main source root, only the sources specific for the flavor("BrandX") - typically it is going to be stuff like UI elements and logic that are not common. With properly defined source sets the sequence of putting classes together is:

```
main -> flavour_1 -> flavour_2 -> releaseType
```

`flavour_2` can utilize anything that comes from `flavour_1` - as long as the signature is the same.

Also, you can have source directories that explicitly define the combination of flavors/dimensions - even without explicitly defining them as source sets. e.g. `"src/Brand1Brand2/java"`. (Note: this assumes 2+ dimensions)

As mentioned, Android Studio doesn't automatically generate source folders for you, you have to create them manually.

Regarding AndroidManifest files, each flavor can have its own - they end up merged into one but that's also a quite long topic and out of the scope of this question. To define the flavor version, just add `manifest.srcFile()` to the source set for the flavor.

How you end up separating the source code will eventually be up to you. From my experience, it relied heavily on Default/Base classes for UI and hiding logic behind interfaces which each flavor source set was providing through their module for dependency injection(DI/Hilt).